# Background image position with padding

Tags: html, css, background-image, positioning

I have an icon set as background, as shown below:

[image]

As you can see there must be padding right after the arrow to have nice space.
How can I solve this issue?

HTML

```
<span class="arrowIcon">Newsletter Sign up</span>
```

CSS

```
.arrowIcon{
  background-image:url(../img/arrow.png);
  background-position:right center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:#5379A5;
  padding:10px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  float:right;
  width:55%;
}
```

Comment: you can add background-position:90% center;

Comment: use background position and adjust x value as your wish.

Answer (score 5):

You can position a background image FROM the right by writing this in your css.

```
background-position: right 10px center;
```

I consider this to be the cleanest solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `calc`.

```css
#test {
  background-color: moccasin;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('http://www.math.muni.cz/~bulik/gifs/arrow.small.left.gif');
  background-position: calc(100% - 10px) center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a right border with the same color as the background :

`border-right: 10px solid #5379A5;`

Answer (score 0):

A background image does not take padding into account, use background-position for that or split up your `<span>` into `<span>newsletter sign up<img></img></span>` .

Answer (score 0):

Here it is :

```css
.arrowIcon {
  background-image: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/7/6/4/a/1206569902228245216pitr_green_single_arrows_set_1.svg.hi.png);
  background-position: 95% center;
  /* adjust the 98% as your needs or put px value instead if you know extact div size */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #5379A5;
  background-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  width: 55%;
  
  /* to display correctly in SO */
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<span class="arrowIcon">Newsletter Sign up</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have given float:right its going to be in right .